# Memory usage and overwrites in c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, vector

I am working on a large piece of code.  As part of my main class constructor I declare a large number of vectors which at one point or another get filled (all with doubles).  Up until a while ago the code ran fine but after I added one further vector of doubles a completely unrelated variable (one which decides whether a particular 'run' has been succesfull or not) is being changed for some reason.
I have not added any lines which change this success variable and when I print out it's value (a succesful run leads to the variable being zero) it changes to a massive integer everytime, but each time I run it gives a different value.
I have a feeling I am doing something wrong with memory allocation but I don't know what exactly!
Any advice welcomed,
Cheers
Jack

## UPDATE

```
class MyClass {
            std::vector <std::vector<HLV> > qChains;    
    std::vector <std::vector<HLV> > VertexChains;
    std::vector <std::vector<double> > Virtuals;    
    std::vector <double> VProducts;         
    std::vector <double> QProducts;         
    std::vector <double> StrongCouplings;       
            int EventStatus
}
```

and then in another method of 'MyClass' I have a quick if loop checking the event is going ok:

```
if (GetEventStatus() != 0) cout << "ERROR!! " << GetEventStatus() << endl;
```

and ever since I added the line about StrongCouplings the status has been returning random huge integers.
I have however noticed that if I place a series of print statements throughout checking the value of EventStatus at various places the problem goes away!

Comment: at least show us some code

Comment: Show some code, any code.  What is the code you changed?  What did it look like before.  We have absolutely nothing to go on right now.

Comment: Like I say the code is well in excess of 10k lines, and distributed across a tonne of files.  I will add an excerpt from the class definition if that will help?

Comment: Just out of curiosity what type of "variable" accepts an added vector of doubles?  Did you add a field to a struct or class?  Please show us that.  (Also, what's an `HLV`?)  PS - I notice some missing semicolons.

Comment: Hi ebyrob yes I added another vector to a class

Comment: Hello again, HLV is a typedef for CLHEP::HepLorentzVector (http://proj-clhep.web.cern.ch/proj-clhep/doc/CLHEP_2_0_4_7/doxygen/html/classCLHEP_1_1HepLorentzVector.html)
 and the missing semicolons are only in my above quick bit of code not the full thing - it compiles under g++ fine :)

Comment: This could be a silly point of view, but are you sure your code is not linking against an expurious binary object? Try to remove all "*.o" objects and issue a clean "make".

Comment: The variable are defined fine. Personally I wouldn't use a vector of vectors because it's horribly slow if the outer vector need to grow. The problem is somewhere in the code. most likely by incorrectly using the vector [] operator.

Answer (score 0):

try to add char buf[128]; before the variable that changes its value - if its helps - it will mean some previous variable overrides your variable. It may be caused by ODR violation or  by incorrect usage of a C array (if you write after the end of the array)

Comment: after your UPDATE. the sample seems ok. one stupid question. Did you fully rebuild your project?

Comment: I did yeah, it's really weird but once I realised the cout statements which just printed the value of the variables getting changed was helping I removed them again to see what would happen and now the variable it's jumping around anymore!